# Charset UTF-8 does not display Umlauts

Tags: php, forms, utf-8

Well, as a Webdeveloper, german language sucks.

I have a from. In the head, there is at the first place:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I also checked the header. The following is set:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

In php.ini my default-charset is:

```
default_charset="utf-8"
```

The problem is in HTML/PHP because when I write Umlauts (äöü) directly in the database, PHP gets the right string, when I var_dump it.
On the other side when I fill out the textarea and send the form, the var_dump for the POST-Parameter has everytime 2 questionmarks instead of the Umlauts.

```
ä -> ??
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to set `accept-charset="UTF-8"` in HTML form?

Comment: Jep... no change at all.

Comment: I'm sure that the problem is not in the HTML but in the database connection. How are you connecting to your database and have you issued `SET NAMES UTF8` after establishing connection?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Ha! Try yourself on *Japanese* one of these days… ;-P

Answer (score -1):

I despair, so I added some Javascript, which replace the Umlauts in the Textbox-Value until the form is sending.

```
$('form').submit( function(ev) {
var textarea = $('form textarea');
var text = textarea.val();

   text = text.replace(/ä/g,"&auml;");
   text = text.replace(/ö/g, '&ouml;');
   text = text.replace(/ü/g, '&uuml;');
   text = text.replace(/Ä/g, '&Auml;');
   text = text.replace(/Ö/g, '&Ouml;');
   text = text.replace(/Ü/g, '&Uuml;');
   text = text.replace(/ß/g, '&szlig;');

   textarea.val(text);
});
```

In PHP I use html_entity_decode to write the data in the database.

```
    $sql_arr = array(
       'descr'     =>  html_entity_decode($db->sql_escape($request->variable('description', ''))),
       // Some more Data
    );
```